# With spatie/laravel-tags plugin get related items

Tags: laravel-5, tags

Using `spatie/laravel-tags` plugin (https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-tags/v2/basic-usage/using-tags) in my Laravel 5.7 app.

My `Vote` model (`app/Vote.php`) has tags:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use DB;
use App\MyAppModel;
...
use Spatie\Tags\Tag as SpatieTag;
use Spatie\Tags\HasTags;

class Vote extends MyAppModel
{
    use HasTags;

    protected $table = 'votes';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
```

and I try by found Tag get all related Votes, which has this tag, like:

```
    $activeTag = Tag::containingSlug($tag_slug)->first();
    $tagRelatedVotes= Vote::withAnyTags( [$activeTag->slug], 'votesTagType' )->get();
```

But tagRelatedVotes is empty and looking at sql trace I see next:

```
   SELECT * 
    FROM `tags` 
    WHERE LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(slug, "$.en")) like '"%animals%"' limit 1 


   SELECT * 
    FROM `tags` 
    WHERE `name`->'$."en"' = '{"en": "animals"}'     AND `type` = 'votesTagType' limit 1 


   SELECT * 
    FROM `votes` 
    WHERE 
    EXISTS (  SELECT * 
    FROM `tags` 
    INNER JOIN `taggables` on `tags`.`id` = `taggables`.`tag_id` 
    WHERE `votes`.`id` = `taggables`.`taggable_id`     AND `taggables`.`taggable_type` = 'App\Vote'     AND `id` in (''))
```

The 1st statement find the row, but the second statement finds nothing and that is strange why name field is used in request ?
So the 3rd statement is invalid. Which is the valid way?

MODIFIED BLOCK # 2:
Thank you for your feedback!
I tried as you wrote, but I got empty results.
I sql trace I see next:

```
   SELECT * 
    FROM `tags` 
    WHERE LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(slug, "$.en")) like '"%thriller%"' limit 1 


   SELECT * 
    FROM `tags` 
    WHERE `name`->'$."en"' = '{"en": "Thriller"}'     AND `type` = 'votesTagType' limit 1 


   SELECT * 
    FROM `votes` 
    WHERE 
    EXISTS (  SELECT * 
    FROM `tags` 
    INNER JOIN `taggables` on `tags`.`id` = `taggables`.`tag_id` 
    WHERE `votes`.`id` = `taggables`.`taggable_id`     AND `taggables`.`taggable_type` = 'App\Vote'     AND `id` in (''))
```

The 1st statement returned 1 row, but the second returned nothing, but I have 1 row with name= 'Thriller' and `type` = 'votesTagType'.
I am not sure what expression

```
`name`->'$."en"' = '{"en": "Thriller"}'
```

means, that is beyond my mysql expierence. CXan it be some mysql or this plugin options?
I have :

```
   SELECT version() : 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the `name` of the Tag to the `withAnyTags()` method. [docs](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-tags/v2/basic-usage/retrieving-tagged-models)

```
$activeTag = Tag::containingSlug($tag_slug)->first();
$tagRelatedVotes= Vote::withAnyTags( [$activeTag], 'votesTagType' )->get();
```

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED BLOCK # 2

Comment: Was it misspelling, that set object in array [$activeTag] to withAnyTags ?

Comment: You can pass the whole Tag model to `withAnyTags()`, instead of just the name

Comment: why is my function being empty? I think i have the same thing as OP only that im using a function to retrieve the slug 
```$tag = Tag::findFromSlug($slug);``` ```$posts = Post::withAnyTags([$tag])->get();```